# Function passing null at first run

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

i have a little problem with passing data into a JSON file. I have a function that runs `onClick`. The first run returned:

```js
{
   "title": "",
   "description": "",
   "price": "",
   "id": 1
}
```

but all next runs returns data correctly:

```js
{
   "title": "Example title",
   "description": "Example description",
   "price": "$7",
   "id": 2
}
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

My react code:

```js
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('');

    const addToCart = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTitle('Example title');
        setDescription('Example description');
        setPrice('$' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1));

        const product = { title, description, price};

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/basket', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(product)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because setState is async and only update when component re-render. So you can declare variable to use in post and in setState.

```
const addToCart = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const product = {
    title: "Example title",
    description: "Example description",
    price: "$" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1),
  };

  setTitle(product.title);
  setDescription(product.description);
  setPrice(product.price);

  fetch("http://localhost:8000/basket", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(product),
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely breaking because you're trying to set state while making a fetch call, on initial empty state values.  The design here is wrong, you shouldn't be assigning hard coded state while making a fetch call.

```
const Form = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const submit = () => {
    // make fetch call here using value
  }

  return <form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); submit()}}>
    <input type='text' value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
  </form>
}
```